# service block based on agent size in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

My shop floor is divided into 4 quadrants, each occupied by a welder. For the small products it could occupy 1 quadrant but for large products, it will occupy 2 quadrants with 2 welders working on it. How can I translate that in anylogic using service building block? I already have my product size determined at the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a ResourceType "Quadrant".
2. Create a ResourcePool with 4 resources of type "Quadrant"
3. Set up your Service block such that each bit of work needs 1 welder
4. before that, create a seize block that seizes "quadrant" resources based on the product type. See pic below where I assume this is stored in Product.type as a String:
5. don't forget to create a release block as well downstream of the Service.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now I need to make sure that diagonal quadrants arent occupied for a large module because that is not feasible, it has to be adjacent. Im new to Anylogic...

Comment: First, please mark this question as "useful" if it solved the original problem (helps others find it faster if they have similar problems). For your problem, you will need to do this manually: either as specific code in the "seize custom resource unit" setting of a Seize block or by using 4 RPs and seizing them based on conditions.